# How do I test whether the distribution of effect sizes are different across intervention types?

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size

I've extracted 3,456 Cohen's d effect sizes from published studies, and categorized each based on intervention type (four different intervention types). I did this to understand the distribution of reported effect sizes, not to perform a meta-analysis. The idea was the quartile values of the distribution could inform interpretation of small, medium, and large treatment effects.

I would like to test whether the distribution of effect sizes differ by intervention type. Is it valid to use a Kruskal-Wallis test for this purpose? If not, what would be an appropriate method for answering this question?

Thanks in advance,
Adam